# Using Paging 3 to paginate a list with a startRecord and an endRecord

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I am using paging 3 and cannot find my use case in the available tutorials.
basically I paste is the example i find in the documentation and in all the tutorials on line, basically `backend.searchUsers(query, nextPageNumber)` does not fit my case I have just to call `backend.fetchAList(userId,startRecord,endRecord)` so basically I need to ask to the back end to giving to me only a specific range of pages, let's say I want 16 items per time, I guess I should ask `startRecord:0 endRecord:15` then I do not know how if user scrolls at the end of the list I should ask `startRecord:16 endRecord:31` and so on, till the end of the list. How can I achieve that with Paging3?

> EDIT: I am assuming that my approach should be like I mention above my
> use case is: as user I want to retrieve a list with PaginatedData to
> fill my adapter, loading the list gradually so that the use scroll a
> certain number of pages and then new ones are retrieved from the back end, with the condition that the back end has these fields: startRecord: Int; endRecord:Int, hasNextItems: Boolean, List, totalItems: Int

```
class ExamplePagingSource(
    val backend: ExampleBackendService,
    val query: String
) : PagingSource<Int, User>() {
  override suspend fun load(
    params: LoadParams<Int>
  ): LoadResult<Int, User> {
    try {
      // Start refresh at page 1 if undefined.
      val nextPageNumber = params.key ?: 1
      val response = backend.searchUsers(query, nextPageNumber)
      return LoadResult.Page(
        data = response.users,
        prevKey = null, // Only paging forward.
        nextKey = response.nextPageNumber
      )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      // Handle errors in this block and return LoadResult.Error if it is an
      // expected error (such as a network failure).
    }
  }

  override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, User>): Int? {
    // Try to find the page key of the closest page to anchorPosition, from
    // either the prevKey or the nextKey, but you need to handle nullability
    // here:
    //  * prevKey == null -> anchorPage is the first page.
    //  * nextKey == null -> anchorPage is the last page.
    //  * both prevKey and nextKey null -> anchorPage is the initial page, so
    //    just return null.
    return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
      val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
      anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use multiplication to determine your range, and call `backend.fetchAList(userId, PAGE_SIZE * page, (PAGE_SIZE * (page + 1) - 1)`, where `PAGE_SIZE` is 16. For `page` of `0`, this gives you `backend.fetchAList(userId, 0, 15)`. For a `page` of `1`, this gives you ``backend.fetchAList(userId, 15, 31)`. And so on. The value of `page` comes from your key, effectively like how they have `nextPageNumber`, except that you would start with `0` rather than `1`.

Comment: thank you @CommonsWare mark you are a community lifesafer